# Изменить значение переменной-массива

Tags: c++

Можно ли как нибудь поменять значение переменной `char[]`?

Пример:

```
char a[80];
if (b=d) a="qwerty";
else if (o=f) a="poiuyt";
```

Comment: можно) но лучше бы вы `string` использовали.

Answer (score 4):

Переменная `a` это массив, и литерал `"qwerty"` это массив. А массивы присваивать нельзя.

Поэтому надо например сделать `a` указателем, т.е. `const char* a;`,
либо копировать массивы при помощи `strcpy`

```
char a[80];
if (b == d) strcpy(a, "qwerty");
```

Однако операции с обычными массивами чреваты переполнениями буфера, так что лучше использовать `std::string`.

Comment: Встает философский вопрос, кстати: что такое " значение переменной char[]" - указатель на место в памяти, где находится массив (сама `a`), или значения в соответствующих местах в памяти? Потому как на первый вопрос ответ категорически отрицательный, поменять значение переменной `a` невозможно :)

Answer (score 0):

Вся интересующая Вас информация [тут](http://cppstudio.com/post/437/).

> UPD

Первый способ:

```
char a[50];
strcpy(a, "Hello World!");
```

Второй способ:

```
char a[50];
char b[13] = {"Hello World!"};
for(int i(0);i<13;i++)
{
    a[i] = b[i];
}
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/104563)

Comment: За что заминусовали??? Есть много способов изменить массив символов! Ссылку я привел, автор пусть сам выбирает какой способ ему нужен! Привел 2 простых примера и дополнил сообщение

Comment: @A K - теперь является ответом на вопрос?

Comment: @Streletz - исправил, убери минус.

Comment: А, я и не минусовал вовсе. На замечания из очереди проверок обижаетесь зря. Помимо автора, топик может прочесть любой пользователь сети. И от ответа со ссылкой на страницу, которая "переехала" или удалена пользы не будет никакой. То что Вы исправили ответ, это хорошо. Единственное, немного поправил код (его всё-таки лучше форматировать).

Comment: @Streletz - лады, дело не в обиде, а в неадекватности "минусовавших" , видел кучу таких же ответов как у меня - и никто их не минусовал, мне лично достаточно было написать сноску о моей ошибке в ответе, "что мол так и так, лучше дополнить ответ" и я бы сразу же "дополнил\исправил".